# Controller returns a blank view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to send some data to the view via the below code to the concerned view (/view/modifier.phtml):

```
public function modifierAction()
{        
    $compte = 'aa';
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'compte' => $compte,
    ));
}
```

But, the view which I get back isn't the wished one. I'm getting a blank page.

How to fix that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well multiple things could be the issue

*What is your layout.phtml?*

If it is empty, you should output some html. With `<?php echo $content; ?>` you output the view html.

---

*Is it a blank page or no code?*

- blank page issue of css/html
- no code issue with layout

---

*Do you have an other action working?*

If not what is working?

---

*Do you get to `modifierAction`?*

Do a simple `die('test');`

---

Like @notuser pointed out

It could also be that `display errors` is off or `error reporting` is set to none.